# how to make an android app in linux web server

Tags: android, linux

I want to make android applications by giving users a form and submit on my linux hosted web server.And after taking the details from user i want to create an android app for the user on the linux web server itself.But i dont know how to do the setup for making android application in linux hosted web server.
I have complete setup available in eclipse in my local machine.But is there any way i can make the apps runtime in my linux web server.
I have installed ant and java jdk in linux server but i dont know how android sdk needs to be installed on the server.
Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Yoy have problemas in concepts, Android application is android application, your app always will be in Android device. If you cant to comunicate with linux, you can use a WebService, Rest API of anothe stuffs like this.

When you want to create an android application you need a Android SDK, IDE and Java.

Java  i think you know how to install, install Java JDK.
IDE- Download Android Studio from official website.
Android SDK- Downloand when you have Android Studio.

Comment: I understand ur concepts,But my query is how can i create an android app on web server where a site is hosted and user is filling the form on that site.let me tell you an example sir..
http://www.appsgeyser.com.I want to perform something like this website devs have done.Can you please give me short info how these guys have done.

Comment: Well i see... 
You use a template and they create a hybrid app, in other words it is a webapp or an app with HTML5, JS, CSS and probably some framework or technology as phonegap or sencha, Cordova. Actually they will generate a hybrid app and you get the APK of this app.

Comment: k.k.it means they are using phonegap like tool with which they can develop the app on server in HTML or frontnend languages.Correct me if i m wrong please.

Comment: I am not 100% sure about use phonegap but... 99% sure they use HTML5,JS,CSS, because the interface si HTML and is the same like anothers web they use the same technology to create websites. Usually when use html,css,js is commmon use support like phonegap, etc.